# Group recursive 1:M relationship

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a recursive 1:M

Every customer may have been referred by a previous customer, now I want to group the customers who have made referrals, so I can display which ones have referred the most.

[image]

and I would want a query which gave following output

[image]

I tried

```
SELECT count(*) AS Count_of_referrals, referral_id
FROM Customer
GROUP BY referral_id
```

which gives the amount of times each referral_id is mentioned, but I can't find a way to link this back to the actual customer who referred them.

Appreciate any help I can get here.. :-)

Comment: Post your tables and the wanted result as text please.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're close. You just need to self join the `customer` table to get the `name` of the `referral_id` in there.

```
SELECT c1.referral_id,
       c2.name,
       count(*) count_of_referrals
       FROM customer c1
            INNER JOIN customer c2
                       ON c2.customer_id = c1.referral_id
       GROUP BY c1.referral_id,
                c2.name;
```